# Jenkins CI and SFDX

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, ci

Do we need to learn Groovy language to start using Jenkins CI with SFDX?

is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think technically no (because Jenkins have [Declarative Pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline)) but I never used to tell you.

In the other hand, you can use other libraries that can make the job easier, such as this [one](https://github.com/claimvantage/sfdx-jenkins-shared-library) (I helped to develop this library). You can also check [Cumulus CI](https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to see if that helps you.